# creepy black boxes in question

Tags: discussion, support

On the active page, I see little black boxes instead of…what?

[image]
It didn't help that Emily's avatar is almost black too, but 
once inside...

[image: EL&U Question page about *x* and *y* be real numbers + little black box and *a* be an integer]

Is this black box supposed to be a glyph or an emoji?  I am like that boy in *the sixth sense*, I see dead boxes. Am I alone?

EDIT
Acck! I read the question, the little black boxes are supposed to be commas or blanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks  like this is intentional: Kenny LJ used the Unicode character "black box" to mark the places that may or may not need a comma.